# Компиляция исходного кода в командной строке VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция

Есть репозиторий с [исходниками](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig), пытаюсь скомпилировать их через командную строку VS2013, выполняя команду cl C:/path/file
где file — файл содержащий функцию int main  (правильно ли?)

На выходе получаю кучку ошибок.

Comment: У вас имеется целый проект, а вы компилируете только один файл... Понятно, что так ничего не получится. P.S. Только не спрашивайте, как это сделать :) - там как я вижу, заточено под CMake... Читайте мануалы...

Comment: Cmak'ом собираю проект, но с компиляцией его так же возникли проблемки.
Возможно ли скомпилировать проект, собранный cmak'ом через ком.строку?

Comment: "Возникли проблемки" и "получаю кучку ошибок" - это не осмысленное описание проблемы. У вас есть вопрос?

Comment: Для каких целей это требуется? Вы хотите реализовать continuous integration?

Answer (score 1):

Установите cmake.

Создайте папку для артефактов билда:
(в `.gitignore` уже есть папка `build`)

```
cd path/to/xmrig
mkdir build
```

Сгенерируйте файлы проекта, по умолчанию это будет VC++.
Возможно, это надо делать из консоли с переменными окружения VC++.

```
cd build
cmake ..
```

Соберите проект

```
cmake --build .
```